# android edittext characters alignment, colors and size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

In my Application, 
    the user should be allowed to change the alignment , color ,size and other texting attributes ,but it implements alignment change to all text content, and size and color are returning to first view ,when I touch out of box

So i want to know how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use spandable .

for your text color use **ForegroundColorSpan** :

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello Everyone");
ForegroundColorSpan colorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(
        context.getResources()
        // Specify your color
        .getColor(R.color.your_font_color));
realPrice.setSpan(colorSpan,
         0, // Start index of the single word
         4, // End index of the single word
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
yourEditText.setText(ssb);
```

and for your text size do like this :

```
String s= "Hello Everyone";
 SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(s);
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,5, 0); // set size
ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);// set color
TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText(ss1);
```

put your string instead of "Hello Everyone"